# What does `cc_test` and `bazel test` really do?

Tags: bazel

Before I use bazel, I always need the following code to start all the test.

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml";
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:./test_detail.xml"
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
int iRet = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

But `cc_test` and `bazel test` seems don't need this, It only need the test code.

So what `cc_test` and `bazel test` ready does? How should I configure gtest now?

Comment: I found this page [Writing Tests](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html) helps a lot but still not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your `cc_test()` rules depend on `@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main` ([source](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/0599a7b8410dc5cfdb477900b280475ae775d7f9/BUILD.bazel#L109)), which defines the `main()` function. If that doesn't do what you want, you can replace `@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main` with a reference to your own `cc_library()` that does, or by adding a `main()` function to every `*_test.cc` file.